# How to print sentences in both threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class X1 extends Thread {
 public void run() {
    System.out.println("I am X1");
  }
}

class Y2{
  public void run() {
    while (true)
    System.out.println("I am Y2");
  }
}

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] s) {
    X1 a = new X1();
    Y2 b = new Y2();
    
    b.run();
    a.start();
  }
}
```

This code is supposed to display both “I am X1” and an infinite number of “I am Y2”. But it only prints “I am Y2”. How to fix it?

Comment: You run `b.run()` in the hosting thread. It got an infinite loop inside of it so it never gets outside of the `run()` method and thus never calls `a.start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.run()` doesn't start a new thread. It executes the `run()` method on the main thread. And since that method contains an infinite loop, it never terminates, so `a.start()` is never executed, and the second thread is never started.

You can either reverse the order of the calls:

```
a.start(); // first start the second thread
b.run(); // then run the infinite loop on the main thread
```

Or run `b`'s `run()` method on a separate thread:

```
new Thread(() -> b.run()).start();
a.start();
```

Or if you change `Y2` to implement `Runnable`:

```
new Thread(b).start();
a.start();
```